# How to run 3 API calls that depends on eachother?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Hello I am attepting to make a webpage to dowload reports from amazon seller central using the MWS API. The issue im running into is that 3 different calls are needed to download one report!

Request report and get its ID-> check status/get report ID -> download report.

Currently I have this running of 3 separate buttons which need to be clicked in order, how would I go about making the second api call wait for the frist one to return a specific value and so on.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/index.html

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: I didnt show code only because it was more about the process of doing it more than being stuck with a specific piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Have a long running PHP process which does it all in one go. You might have to flush() data to the client so that it doesn't appear to hang.
2. Have different PHP scripts doing the three parts (you might want to combine step 2 and 3) and call them through JavaScript in a "polling loop".

Since MWS reports can sometimes take very long (on occasion >1 hr), you'll probably have to change PHP settings to allow such a long running script. I'd personally go with method 2.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply I will get straight on it!

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are doing this from a webpage, I assume your language of choice is JavaScript. Here are JavaScript examples of making a call, and chaining other calls to it. Depending on the library/framework you are using, you can leverage promises, observables or callbacks.

**Promises** (don't forget to check for errors, I don't check in my example):

```
http.get(reportUrl).then(reportResponse => {
    http.get(checkStatusUrl + reportResponse.id).then(statusResponse => {
        http.get(finalUrl + statusResponse.id).then(finalResponse => {
            console.log(finalResponse);
        })
    })
})
```

**Observables**:

```
http.get(reportUrl).subscribe(reportResponse => {
    http.get(checkStatusUrl + reportResponse.id).subscribe(statusResponse => {
        http.get(finalUrl + statusResponse.id).subscribe(finalResponse => {
            console.log(finalResponse);
        })
    })
})
```

**Callbacks**:

```
http.get(reportUrl, reportResponse => {
    http.get(checkStatusUrl + reportResponse.id, statusResponse => {
        http.get(finalUrl + statusResponse.id, finalResponse => {
            console.log(finalResponse);
        })
    })
})
```

---

If you're using a server-side language, your API should look more or less the same. Make the first request, wait for its response. Use the response to make the second request, and so on.

Comment: Sorry thats my fault I haven't used stack before the language I was using is php  but your response defiantly helps!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you make ajax calls,

- you can set `async: false`
- you can set the next ajax call as a callback
- you can call the next ajax call in your calls success function